# Search for word under cursor without moving the cursor

Tags: vim

When I use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> it will trigger a search for the word under the cursor. However, the cursor moves to the next/previous occurrence of that word. Is there a way to search for the current word without having the cursor moving away?

It is annoying because often I want to press

1. <kbd>*</kbd>
2. `:.,+5s/foo/bar/g`

But this problem forces me to do

1. <kbd>*</kbd>
2. then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> (I want to skip this)
3. my search and replace.

Comment: I fail to see the connection between step 1 and step 2.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there a way to search for the current word without having the cursor moving away?

The whole point of `*`, `#`, and friends is made pretty clear in the documentation: "search forward" or "search backward". Your problem seems to be that you use those commands not for their intended purpose but for a side effect, presumably highlighting all occurrences of the word under the cursor.

Since there's no built-in command for that you will need to map it yourself:

```
nnoremap <key> *``
nnoremap <anotherkey> #``
...
```

Comment: Thank you I believe you answered my question. There are no built in function for this but it can be mapped into my .vimrc .

Comment: To keep jumps, use ´m`:keepjumps normal! *``´ and note, that gstar also works for no word boundary search.

Comment: Interestingly enough, searching in another window does not work and one needs to set `/` register: `<cmd>let @/='\<'.expand("<cword>").'\>'<Bar>wincmd w<Bar>normal n<CR><cmd>wincmd w<CR>`. Note, that vimscript doesnt like long command chains here.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of pressing <kbd>*</kbd> to fill the search pattern copy the word directly to command line using [CTRL-R CTRL-W](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W). I.e.:

```
:.,+5s/<C-R><C-W>/bar/g
```

Comment: this is prefect for what i need... using :g/<ctrl-r><ctrl-w>/p to find and jump to the instance of the word i want

Comment: good tip. You know what would be cooler though? nnoremap <leader># :let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<C-M>
nnoremap <leader>sh :set hlsearch!<CR>

Comment: how do you find such thing in the documentation *eyeroll*. Thanks! Is there a similar keybinding/combination for searching multiple words/phrases?

Comment: @MacMartin `vim` is one of my primary tools for about 25 years. Once or twice I read the docs completely. Since that I regularly rescan the docs (esp. when a new major release is out) to find out new gems and tricks. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could map:

```
nnoremap # #N
nnoremap * *N
```

Comment: Simple and efficient solution

Answer (score 3):

I use the below mapping to search the current word and keep cursor's posistion:

```
nnoremap <expr> * ':%s/'.expand('<cword>').'//gn<CR>``'
```

The extra benefit is we got matches count too.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the functionality of `*` / `#` / `g*` etc. to *not* jump (especially without a given `[count]`) is a frequent request. Therefore, a plethora of plugins changes Vim's default behavior, often together with other search-related commands. My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) is one such plugin. (The plugin page has links to many alternative plugins that could also try out.)

@romainl's accepted answer is a minimal solution with some drawbacks (e.g. flickering of the screen, possible change of window viewport) that most plugins will avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
noremap * :let @/ = "\\<<C-r><C-w>\\>"<cr>:set hlsearch<cr>
```

It simply sets the search pattern to the whole word under the cursor and then triggers an update to the search highlighting