# Vim: search word under cursor (not * or #)

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to replicate Sublime Text's "CTRL-D" behavior which highlights the current word under the cursor.

<kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> don't work here, because they automatically move the cursor (like <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>), which I explicitly don't want.

In order to hightlight the current word under the cursor, I have found the following to be effective:

```
yiw
:let @/=@@
:set hls
```

If you type this **manually** it works just fine, as intended.

My problem is that I just don't get it what I do wrong to put this on a keymap so I can bind it.

What I've tried so far is:

1. create a function, then map it to a key:

   ```
   function SearchWordUnderCursor()
       silent! yiw
       silent! :let @/ = @@
       silent! :set hls
   endfunction
   ```
2. use the inline keybinding, like so:

   ```
   nmap <C-D> yiw | :let @/ = @@ | :set hls
   ```

Both methods don't work as intended and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The search pattern/register is set just fine, but the immediate highlighting is not working, you'd have to manually <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> once to display the highlighting, but that moves the cursor, as opposed to the "manual" method.

Why is it so hard to get it done as if it was typed manually?

I'm using NVIM v0.2.2.

Comment: Have you considered plugins? [Vim Mark](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) works nicely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for word under cursor without moving the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097790/search-for-word-under-cursor-without-moving-the-cursor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you remove `silent!` from the code vim helpfully cries `yiw: not an editor command`.

In a function every line is `:` (ex-)command. Your `yiw` is equivalent to `:yiw` and this is not an editor command. (This also means that you can safely omit `:` before commands). To run a Normal-mode command say [`:normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) explicitly:

```
function SearchWordUnderCursor()
    silent! normal yiw
    silent! let @/ = @@
    silent! set hls
endfunction
```

2. In a mapping you need to separate commands with `<BAR>` instead of `|` and pass **all** the keys you press including <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

---

```
nmap <C-D> yiw <BAR> :let @/ = @@<CR> <BAR> :set hls<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple, non-cursor moving solution is

```
nnoremap <C-D> *N
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one does not work, because you must use `normal! yiw` in VimScript (as VimScript statements are `:commands`, and not normal-mode keys).

The second one does not work, because these are keys, not Ex-commands, and so you must put in `:` and `<CR>` where it's appropriate (and also to escape all "bars" with backslashes, as the first "bar" will end the "map"-command otherwise).

So you should read more about normal mode vs. command-line mode.

Also, using `hlsearch` does not look nice, as you are not searching anything. It's better IMO to use `:h :match` instead. For example,

```
nnoremap <C-D> :execute 'match Search /\V' . escape(expand('<cword>'), '\/') . '/'<CR>
```

Use `:match NONE` to switch it off.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to solve this issue:

```
" [I shows lines with word under the cursor
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>
nnoremap <Leader>* :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>

if !exists('*CountWordFunction')
    fun! CountWordFunction()
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
            exec "%s/" . expand("<cword>") . "//gn"
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfun
endif
```

You can use these options

```
1 - double mouse clik
2 - <leader>*
```